# Parallel processing of samples in DirectShow filter

Tags: winapi, parallel-processing, directshow

I have a transform filter.
How in DirectShow implement high-performance filter, capable to process multiple media samples in same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything built in, however any general parallelization technique can be applied. Typical ideas include creating a pool of threads well in advance (stop to pause transition); making a media sample available for threads, then synchronizing with the workers to compose output sample; pushing an incoming media sample into queue, where an idle thread takes it for processing, then pushes complete work back into output queue.

Comment: I understand, but how i can get next frame before complete processing current sample and sending downstream. I have `Transform(ref MediaSample input,ref MediaSample output)` method, i can`t queue frame couse before i return control from method i must fill output sample. Thank you Roman R. .

Comment: `Transform` limits you to processing one frame at a time. If you need to make it more flexible doing multiple frames at once, e.g. the way MS DTV/DVD Decoder does it, you will have to inherit from generic base filter class, not transform filter. With transform you can only do parallelization with separate frame.